# Angular Upgrade From 5 to 6: asset path must start with the project source root

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I upgraded my existing app from Angular 5 to 6.

After i run `ng serve` i get the following error:

> The node_modules/font-awesome/fonts asset path must start with the
>   project source root. Error: The node_modules/font-awesome/fonts asset
>   path must start with the project source root.
>       at assetPatterns.map.assetPattern (/home/kay/Documents/<>/<>/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-asset-patterns.js:37:23)

As you can see below i have an assets array that pulls in fonts from the node module package. This was not an issue in Angular 5.

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/theme.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
              "node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.min.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "node_modules/ua-parser-js/dist/ua-parser.min.js",
              "node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js",
              "node_modules/wordcloud/src/wordcloud2.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
              "node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.min.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "node_modules/ua-parser-js/dist/ua-parser.min.js",
              "node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js",
              "node_modules/wordcloud/src/wordcloud2.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/theme.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "demo-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "demo:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "demo",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 62):

Ok,
Clarifying Abann's solution. **You must use the long form** for assets outside the `sourceRoot`. I do think the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration) could be much more clear on that. It states

> You can use this extended configuration to copy assets from outside your project. For instance, you can copy assets from a node package:

But really, it should say *you **must** use*

```
"assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico",
           {
            "glob": "*",
            "input": "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts",
            "output": "assets/fonts/"
          }
        ],
```

Where `assets/fonts/` is the path you probably configured in your SASS/SCSS file's `$fa-font-path` variable override.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! Thought I was going insane. I want to keep assets outside the main project setup under git vc, so I can have a separate assets repo vc.

Comment: I think it only works when glob is set to `"**/*"`.

Answer (score 15):

Edit 1

Okay try this:

```
"assets": [
    {"glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/youpackage", "output": "/where_you_want_theasset/"}
]
```

reference:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md

Original answer:
since it helped me(all my assets are in src)

I got the same error after updating,

try adding the root of your app to the angular.json

for me the sourceRoot and root are the same

```
"root": "src",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
```

like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "src",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
```

Comment: I don't have sourceRoot in my project, ie, there is no src folder. How to handle this one in angular.json

Comment: This did  not work for me. I am pointing to an asset outside of src within node_modules. It seems like this is not possible anymore...

Comment: what was the solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

changing sourceRoot to '.' seems to have resolved this and allowed me to compile, and a superficial test shows everything working.  not confident that this won't introduce other unintended consequences though.

Answer (score 2):

I received the `The src/assets asset path must start with the project source root` error message after adding a new project to an existing workspace and copying and pasting the development configuration from an existing project's `serve` section into the `serve` section of the new project in my `angular.json` file, but failing to update the `browserTarget` property to reflect the name of the new project. The error message complained about the existing project, which seemed strange to me since I was sure I hadn't modified anything to do with that project.

***WRONG***

Note that the value of `projects.project2.architect.serve.configurations.development.browserTarget` is `project1:build:development` instead of `project2:build:development`.

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "schematics": {
    ...
  },
  "projects": {
    "project1": {
      ...
      "sourceRoot": "projects/project1/src",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "projects/project1/src/assets"
            ],
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              ...
            },
            "production": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "project1:build:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project1:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    },
    "project2": {
      ...
      "sourceRoot": "projects/project2/src",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "projects/project2/src/assets"
            ],
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              ...
            },
            "production": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "project1:build:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project2:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

***RIGHT***

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "schematics": {
    ...
  },
  "projects": {
    "project1": {
      ...
      "sourceRoot": "projects/project1/src",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "projects/project1/src/assets"
            ],
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              ...
            },
            "production": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "project1:build:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project1:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    },
    "project2": {
      ...
      "sourceRoot": "projects/project2/src",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "projects/project2/src/assets"
            ],
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              ...
            },
            "production": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "project2:build:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project2:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true what has been said, but it has to be written a bit differently. This works for me, in my angular JSON

```
"assets": [
              {
                "glob": "assets/**",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message after I upgraded my project to angular 6.x. My project has references to PrimeNG, which uses font awesome. After upgrading PrimeNG to `6.0.0-alpha.2`, the error has gone (their working hard to get angular 6 official supported).

So if you facing this issue, verify that your dependencies support Angular 6.x as well and the installed packages are up to date.